# Symfony2 debug toolbar is not injected Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to make the web debug bar appear in Symfony 2.8 and I somehow cannot make it work.

My template has a closing  Tag. Also WebDebugToolbarListener gets invoked but aborts on this condition:

```
     if (self::DISABLED === $this->mode
        || !$response->headers->has('X-Debug-Token')
        || $response->isRedirection()
        || ($response->headers->has('Content-Type') && false === strpos($response->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'html'))
        || 'html' !== $request->getRequestFormat()
        || false !== stripos($response->headers->get('Content-Disposition'), 'attachment;')
    ) {
        return;
    }

    $this->injectToolbar($response, $request);
```

I debugged and found that "X-Debug-Token" is NEVER included in the headers. That's why injectToolbar method is never invoked. When I comment the specific line `|| !$response->headers->has('X-Debug-Token')` the toolbar would show up, however I receive the Exception:

> "Parameter "token" for route "_wdt" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to
>   generate a corresponding URL."

Also it's obviously the wrong way dealing with this problem.

What am I doing wrong? I am out of ideas.

Here is what I have configured:

```
#config_dev.yml
framework:
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml"
        strict_requirements: true
profiler: { only_exceptions: true }

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false
    position: bottom
```

---

```
//app_dev.php
Debug::enable();

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

---

```
//AppKernel.php
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
    $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
    $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
    $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
    $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
}
```

---

```
#routing_dev.yml
_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_configurator:
    resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
    prefix:   /_configurator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Apparently I had to enable profiler explicitely (which sets the X-Debug-Token). RTM for the win. I had never done this in the past though.</del>

The key is to set `only_exceptions: false` . Otherwise the profiler would not collect any data and also won't set the X-Debug-Token and thus the toolbar would not attach. I have set this flag to true in the past because my cache directory was growing quite rapidly.

The `enabled` Flag is set to true for dev and test environments by default.

```
#config_dev.yml
framework:
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml"
        strict_requirements: true
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }
```

Comment: Interesting.  I don't have a 2.8 version handy but my out of the box 3.2 app works fine without enabled: true

Comment: Yeah I was wrong, the key was to set `only_exceptions` to false :)